# Solve system of complex differential equations in Octave

Tags: octave

Well, I wanna solve a system of complex ODE in the form:

$ i\hbar \dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \left[ H, \rho \right] $

http://mathbin.heroku.com/rq65idQ

where $\rho$ and $H$ are $n x n$ matrices.

I tried to define a general function using:

```
function xdot = f(x,t)

i*xdot(1)=
i*xdot(2)=

endfunction
x0=[0;0];
t=linspace(0,20,200);
y=lsode("f",x0,t).
```

but I got a error message concerning the *i* . My question is, then: how to solve a complex differential equation in Octave?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because i is on the LHS of the equal sign rather than the RHS.

Have you tried?

```
xdot(1) = <whatever your RHS expression is> / i;
xdot(2) = <whatever your RHS expression is> / i;
```